# Css scroll content shadow effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am looking for a plugin (similar to sticky header i guess) which creates box-shadow effect on scrollable content (while you scroll down).

I found [an existing technique which is using pure CSS tricks](http://lea.verou.me/2012/04/background-attachment-local/), which does exactly what i need (uses `background-color` property)

However, the scrollable content gets **above** the shadow, and i need it to be below the shadow.

Is there any plugin which creates the same effect but using an inner `div` with shadow and dynamic opacity or something like this?

[image: You can see the white div gets above the shaodow]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to use `box-shadow` and apply it dynamically `onscroll` event depending on scrollTop value. Maybe something like this:

```
document.querySelector('div').onscroll = function() {
    this.classList[this.scrollTop < 20 ? 'add' : 'remove']('shadow-top');
    this.classList[this.scrollHeight - this.clientHeight - this.scrollTop < 20 ? 'add' : 'remove']('shadow-bottom');
};
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/0aevh7kv/

---

**UPD.** I think more what OP wanted is to show shadow on top if div can be scrolled up. In this case, it's even simpler:

```js
document.querySelector('div').onscroll = function() {
    this.classList[this.scrollTop > 20 ? 'add' : 'remove']('shadow-top');
};
```

```css
ul, li { padding: 0; margin: 0; }

div {
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px #AAA solid;
  overflow: auto;
  transition: box-shadow .2s ease;
}
div.shadow-top {
  box-shadow: inset 0 4px 10px -3px #808080;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>text cotent 1</li><li>text cotent 2</li><li>text cotent 3</li><li>text cotent 4</li><li>text cotent 5</li><li>text cotent 6</li><li>text cotent 7</li><li>text cotent 8</li><li>text cotent 9</li><li>text cotent 10</li><li>text cotent 11</li><li>text cotent 12</li><li>text cotent 13</li><li>text cotent 14</li><li>text cotent 15</li><li>text cotent 16</li><li>text cotent 17</li><li>text cotent 18</li><li>text cotent 19</li><li>text cotent 20</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Starting from what you did, i've updated it and it kinda works ([http://jsfiddle.net/f5u92o6w/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/f5u92o6w/1/))

Answer (score 1):

You can use `box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;` for example.
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-box-shadow/

Comment: The shadow needs to be visible only if you have scrolled the content down. It's like a visual feedback that you have content outside the visible scroll area

Comment: @RaraituL You can toggle it with jQuery :)

Comment: If i toggle it (simply show / hide the shadow when i scroll) i won't have a progressive effect. I need the shadow to go from light grey to dark grey based on how much you have scrolled

Comment: @RaraituL You can set an animation with css